# C# : Remove item from list with condition

Tags: c#, list

I try to remove item from list with condition. But the condition doesn't work and all of items are removed.

This is my source code :

```
(Session["AnswerDetail"] as List<T_Answer_Detail>).RemoveAll(a=>a.Answer_Detail_ID==det.Answer_Detail_ID);
```

Is my source code wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems right here... Check what `det.Answer_Detail_ID` is. The error is probably there.

Comment: Can we get a [mcve]?

Comment: If you use the debugger, what is the value of det.Answer_Detail_ID ?

Comment: Thank you guys for all your suggestions. The problem is the answer detail ID. All of ID are same. So all of my list was removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this, it is working for me.

```
var result = Session["AnswerDetail"] as List<T_Answer_Detail>;

result.RemoveAll(a=>a.Answer_Detail_ID==det.Answer_Detail_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

> you can do this :

```
var list = Session["AnswerDetail"] as List<T_Answer_Detail> ;
Session["AnswerDetail"] =list.Remove(list.Where(x=> x.Answer_Detail_ID==det.Answer_Detail_ID))
```